# Why does unicode multiple characters representing the same letter?

Tags: unicode, typesetting, mathematical-typesetting

ASCII has versions of the whole Roman alphabet. I was surprised recently to learn that Unicode contains *other* version/s of those same characters. One example is "U+1D5C4: MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF SMALL K", or "".

Can't LaTeX math mode, or MS Word equation editor, or whatever other program just use a sans-serif font if it wants the letters in a mathematical formula to be sans-serif?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These characters exist so that the semantic distinction between them can be encoded in plain text, or where the specific font shape can't be controlled.

The block you mention is *only* [intended](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L1999/99188.htm) for use in mathematical and technical contexts, where the distinction between, say,  as a variable vs. `d` as a differential operator vs.  as an object (in category theory) is important. [TR #25](http://unicode.org/reports/tr25/) gives another example where losing the distinction between `ℋ` and `H` can completely change the meaning of an equation. Being able to *encode* this formatting into the text itself is also important for [ISO 31-11](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb18-1/tb54becc.pdf).

All of these characters maintain compatibility mappings with their "normal" Latin and Greek counterparts, so the distinction between them should not affect searching and sorting.

Comment: So they said, "We can't have separate characters for d as a variable, operator, object, etc. or we'd have twenty different versions. But serif vs. sans-serif is often used as a way to distinguish between these meanings, so we'll at least have those two"?

Comment: Essentially, yes. It would be almost impossible to go through all of the different uses (as a large number exist, and new ones can be invented), but there are exactly 14 typeface variants.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the display mode with the encoding for texts.

The idea is that unicode has ALL the symbols used to write known to mankind grouped by usage. That's why you will find many code-points that look alike.

So a formula with a `k` is different is supposed to be different then a word written with a `k`. The `sans-serif` part is just a description of the kind of `k` best used to display. Tomorrow somebody might want to add a `serif k` and then how would you describe the difference?

Comment: OK, I think I mostly follow, but here's the part I still don't get: if mathematical k need a sans-serif version (in case someone later wants to add a serif mathematical k), why don't all the other forms of the letter k? [As far as I can tell](http://graphemica.com/k) most forms of k don't specify whether they are serif or sans-serif.

Comment: I could not find anything on why they decided to add sans-serif to the mathematical symbols. I'd just take it as it is: a name for the symbol.